# how to auto inject multiple beans into an ArrayList property with spring and its annotation

Tags: java, spring, jsp, autowired

e.g. i have an array list property in my Action.

```
    private ArrayList<SitesBusiness> businesses;
```

and SitesBusiness is nothing but an interface, and this property is intended to contain all beans which implements SitesBusiness.

the question is that i want to use spring annotation mechanism to auto inject all the beans that implements SitesBusiness into businesses.

Any one can help? Many thanks.

i tried to use AutoWired on this method to do the job

```
    @Autowired
    public void addBusiness(SitesBusiness business) {
        System.out.println("SitesAction, addBusiness.DI1210, business.identifier: " + business.getIdentifier());
        for (int i = 0; i < this.businesses.size(); ++i) {
            if (GlobalMethods.getInstance().checkEqual(this.businesses.get(i), business) || GlobalMethods.getInstance().checkEqual(this.businesses.get(i).getIdentifier(), business.getIdentifier())) {
                return;
            }
        }
        this.businesses.add(business);
     }
```

Unfortunately, this is what i got:

```
     expected single matching bean but found 2: accountBusiness,diaryBusiness
```

Comment: It should work if you replace ArrayList by List

Comment: `@Autowired List<SitesBusiness> businesses;` will work.

Comment: @manish thank you, when change the type to List, Autowired just worked. it totally is a magic to me. i'm sorry i do not know how mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should work:

```
@Autowired
private List<SitesBusiness> businesses;
```

Comment: this is not the situation. which i means is that you can not autowire an ArrayList out there ready to be used. what we have is classes implements SitesBusiness which all annotated with Component. these candidate beans are not grouped to an ArrayList.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. What you will get with this is a List of all beans whose class implements the SitesBusiness Interface. Isn't it what you need?

Comment: yes, but what i mean farther is that the candidate beans is auto created with spring annotation. you can not assume that the list is already ready for a one-time injection.